# How can I determine whether my installer is running on the Education edition of Windows 10?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-10

When I run winver on Windows 10 Education the popup says it is the Education edition, so there must be some way to determine this programatically. I've searched on the internet and cannot find any guidance as to how to do this. Does anyone here know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying WMI Data seems to work. See [Example: Getting WMI Data from the Local Computer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details

Also, see HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion.

Answer (score 2):

[GetProductInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would return `PRODUCT_EDUCATION` in that case.

Comment: I just stumbled across that. The problem is that one has to provide version numbers that cannot accurately be determined on Windows 10. I resorted to examining version numbers of kernel32.dll. This has a file version number with a major version of 6. There shouldn't be any need to provide these details as surely Windows knows it's version number :-).

Comment: You may laugh, but that is actually the recommended way. "To obtain the full version number for the operating system, call the GetFileVersionInfo function on one of the system DLLs, such as Kernel32.dll," https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I'm not laughing at all really.